# Outgoing call is not working after lollipop 5.0.1 update in Samsung Galaxy A5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, calls, sim-card

I have updated my mobile from kitkat to lollipop. After I updated **Outgoing call is not working on 2nd Sim**. On First Sim am using IDEA(sim card) and on Second Sim am using AIRCEL(sim card). So from Aircel outgoing calls are not going, but i can able to access messages and mobile networks from aircel.  Even I removed aircel and inserted another sim called AIRTEL on second sim slot, it is also not working. I tried with many sim but outgoing is not working from 2nd sim.

**Out of box thing** : If I remove IDEA(sim card) from first sim slot and inserted into second sim slot then outgoing call is working!!!.

Help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: It's been a while but have you ever solved it? I'm having similar issues with galaxy s7 edge.